# How to check if my images are saved on Heroku server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

So I am trying to allow the users to upload images to my server to show it on a website later. I am using Multer like this:

```
var uploadLogo = multer({
    dest: './public/images/logos/'
});
.post(uploadLogo.single('logo'), (req, res, next) => {
    var r = req.body;
    account.register(
        new account({
                'employer': {
                    'logo': req.file,
                }
            },
            r.password
        ))
});
```

The interesting thing is, this works on the local version, but images disappear after a while on the online version.

[image]

How can I check if the images exist on the server? Or should I maybe use a 3rd party API like imgur to handle this?

Comment: I recommend using a CDN to deliver your images in your website

Comment: I am trying to allow my users to upload images to my web app. Is there a way to convert this to a CDN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free [Heroku dynos](https://www.heroku.com/dynos) are stopped after some time of inactivity, and all the locally stored data is removed. Consider persisting the images in something like [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

Comment: Would the same happen on a paid version? And where could I find out how much space I have left?

Comment: Check out https://www.heroku.com/pricing. Free dyno: "sleeps after 30 minutes of inactivity", and Hobby dyno ($7 per dyno/month): "never sleeps". I wouldn't rely on the disk storage available to the dyno at all, as it doesn't scale. Just use one of the services that serve this exact purpose, like the S3.